# Multi-thread UI, unable to BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a requirement to launch a window on a separate thread from the main UI thread. It's not ideal, I know it's not normal.

The new window is launched as follows:

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    var w = new ScrollingBanner(300,70,0,0);
                    w.Show();
                    w.Name = "BannerThread";

                    w.Closed += (sender2, e2) => w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

                    Dispatcher.Run();
                });               
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();

        }
```

This launches the window and performs the action I need it to.

The control on the Window of this (threaded) UI calls an event I'm listening for in the code behind the window, as below:

```
 private void ContentTicker_OnScrollComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Scroller Ended");

        try
        {
            if (CheckAccess())
            {
                sliderText.Text = "Updated Text";
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                       new Action(() => sliderText.Text = "Updated Text"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //breakpoint
        }        
    }
```

ContentTicker_OnScrollComplete is called from a background thread under which the control runs.

I get an exception, a different thread owns the control; but as far as I'm aware I'm calling the Dispatcher to perform the action on the correct thread. (which works if I do all this on the main UI thread)

How can I update "sliderText" on the correct thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                   new Action(() => sliderText.Text = "Updated Text"))
```

For this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                   new Action(() => sliderText.Text = "Updated Text"))
```

because `Application.Current.Dispatcher` will return the "Main" Dispatcher, not the "Secondary" one.